# virt-install: send guest command from a host script

Tags: pipe, kvm, libvirt, fifo

I can redirect `virt-install` input/output to console with the `--console` option:

```
virt-install \
  --name centos \
  --ram 1024 \
  --os-type linux \
  --os-variant centos7.0 \
  --graphics none \
  --location ~/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1908.iso \
  --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' \
  --console pty,target.type=serial
```

I would like to send console input from a script and for that reason I tried a named pipe. In plain kvm one can use the option:

```
-serial pipe:/tmp/centos
```

where `/tmp/centos` is the named pipe:

```
mkfifo /tmp/centos.in /tmp/centos.out
```

In `virt-install` I tried replacing the `--console` with several combinations along the line of:

```
--console pty,target.type=serial,source.path=/tmp/centos
```

but nothing is available with:

```
cat /tmp/centos.out
```

and nothing is sent to the VM with:

```
echo cmd > /tmp/centos.in
```

How can I pipe commands from a host script to the guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libvirt has native XML for the 'pipe' option: https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCharPipe

With virt-install it should be: `--console pipe,source.path=/path/to/my/pipe`

- edited to remove incorrect syntax

Comment: I get the error `Unknown --console options: ['type']`. I think for virt-install `type=foo` maps just to `--console foo`. However,  with `--console pipe,source.path=/tmp/centos` I get `internal error: character device console0 is not using a PTY`. The same happens replacing `--console` with `--serial`.

Comment: Ah sorry about the 'type' thing. The `is not using a PTY` error is due to virt-install trying to launch `virsh console $VMNAME` at the end of the install I think, which doesn't work with pipes. Try adding `--noautoconsole` to virt-install

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I can script my installations!